# How to send ETH to other accounts without signing

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am creating a dapp. When a user sends 1 ether to the owner account then the owner should send 2 ether to the account which sent 1 ether using web3js.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you wish to use EOAs (Externally Owned Accounts) you have to use transactions. So when an owner receives Ethers, the owner starts another transaction - and signs it. You have to write code which monitors incoming transactions to the address and then triggers a new transaction. To create the new transaction you have to hold the account's private key somewhere so you can sign transactions with it.

This would be trivial to implement with contracts and no extra transaction required.

Answer (score 0):

Better is to use a smart contract which does not even require to listen the events. Just deposit your ethers in smart contract and write a function to send back the double of the value any one sends to the smart contract.

```
receive() payable external {
  require(msg.value > 0, "not enough value received");
  (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value:msg.value*2}("");
  require(success)
}
```